# How to setup email account on Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an application in which i have to send email using default email account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is unavailable on the WP7 emulator since the emulator is feature locked.  To test this you will need an actual device.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/bfd1ceda-151b-4f88-b459-2f348709aadf

Answer (score 7):

Actually if you have a gmail account you can follow the instructions below to add an email account to your emulator. Works great!

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/real-email-accounts-inside

Comment: Thanks, well i had to send mail with the attachment using SDK API.