# Developing email client apps in Windows Phone 7 in C#

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-7

I am starting  windows phone 7 programming. For one of  my program I need to send email. For example I want to send email using google. For desktop application is can do it. For Windows Phone 7 I found  EmailComposeTask term for related on this. But I don't know how to login or sending email using this. I find some code in net but those are not working also. Here is the code:

```cs
EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
emailcomposer.To"<a href="mailto:test@ginktage.com">test@ginktage.com</a>";
emailcomposer.Subject = "subject from test app";
emailcomposer.Body = "This is a test mail from Email Composer";
emailcomposer.Show();
```

But here from which email client the mail is send?
What will be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> i find some code in net but those are not working also.here is the
>   code.........but here from which email client the mail is send?

The phone would launch the installed email client.  I would assume if Windows Phone is anything like Android this would depend on which application the user selected as the default.

Have you actually ran this code to see what it does.  What you are trying to do is not 100% clear.  What you have right now would simply offer the user to send an email likely using THEIR system email account, certainly would not use your google mail account, or even be guaranteed to use a google account.

Comment: Just to clarify: when this is run and the user has multiple accounts then a page is shown allowing the user to choose which account should be used to send the e-mail.

Comment: @calum - Of course I was just pointing out this code generate an email for the user of the phone to send out, the current code does not send an email in the background, or behave like an email client in the slighest.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to clarify this comment: 'I would assume if Windows Phone is anything like Android this would depend on which application the user selected as the default'. There are no 3rd party E-Mail clients in WP7 so you just get the choice of accounts.

Comment: I run this code in emulator not in real windows phone 7. so there is neither multiple account nor a single account. How can i use the sender email address to send email?

Comment: @MdKamruzzamanPallob I think you should've mentioned in the question that you are trying this with the emulator.

Comment: @Anirudh - Considering this question was asked over a year ago, and the fact it doesn't really change the question's answer, I don't see the point.  Besides you could have easiler proposed that edit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually facing problems because the emulator is feature locked. This question is a repeat of: [How to setup email account on Windows Phone 7 emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208845/how-to-setup-email-account-on-windows-phone-7-emulator) .